# Встроенный в IDE подсказчик Python

Tags: python

Всем привет! Начал изучать Python и был крайне удивлён, что обучаться приходится как и во времена бейсика, по БУМАЖНЫМ книгам! :) Из новшеств за последние 25 лет, это примитивные подсказчики и аналог тех же книг - [стандартный справочник, но на английском](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html). Верить в отсутствие прогресса не хочется, поэтому вопрос к опытным бойцам: Существуют ли встроенные высокоэффективные подсказчики по уровню близкие к подсказчику, например, в Excel? Не примитив типа [этого](http://joxi.ru/YmEaxynFwGddqm) А, что-то, наподобие действительно полезного инструмента? Примеры [1](http://joxi.ru/12MYqeDTlgPBN2),[2](http://joxi.ru/Rmzx4YquYv4PBA),[3](http://joxi.ru/brR5WelS7B55jA),[4](http://joxi.ru/eAOYQe7T9v00Nm),[5](http://joxi.ru/4Ako4zpIojWWxA)

Comment: Сразу прошу прощенья у тех кого могу задеть.
Ненужны такие подсказки в питоне, ибо питон для программистов а эксель для домохозяек.

Comment: есть функция `help()`, например `print(help(str))`, а так, используйте IDE, например PyCharm

Comment: Владимир, нисколько не задеваете, дело вкуса. Каждому своё, кто-то хочет повозиться, а кто-то пытается оптимизировать процесс обучения. :) Excel, здесь упоминается не как среда для программирования :)))), а как ПО содержащий в себе пример, весьма полезного инструмента на порядок ускоряющего обучение. PS Прошу прощения, если задену, но вдруг вспомнился один "мастер болгарки" который любил говорить, что защитные очки придуманы для домохозяек и только мешают работать. :))) По мне, всё, что ускоряет обучение, не только может, но и должно применяться.

Comment: gil9red, спасибо, про help в курсе, пользуюсь... но согласитесь, от "идеального помогатора" это слишком далеко. Help, насколько я помню, 25 лет назад тоже в ходу был. :) про PyCharm понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Использую PyCharm Community Edition. Не смотря на то, что он на английском со временем понимаешь на какую ошибку он указывает. Удобный интерфейс с подсветкой синтаксиса. Рекомендую.
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows 
[[image: пример описания метода[1]]

[image: помощь по оформлению]

Comment: Спасибо! Есть пример, как выглядит подсказка на практике?

Comment: Да, прикрепляю скриншот:

Comment: Спасибо! Да, похоже на то, что это слегка лучше, чем встроенный подсказчик.